# Javascript save variable outside of program

Tags: javascript, variables

I am writing a simple iterator script in a third party program:

```
var i = 1.
function run(){
 output1 = i;
 i = i + 1;
}
```

This function is run for every record. But the program works with batches of 25 records. So for 100 records it outputs 4 times 1 to 25. I have access to the java libs. It is a linux server. Can I put i in some kind of global java variable or memory, so i can live outside of my program? I tried reading and writing i to a text file. This works but is to slow giving me some empty's, ones and two's. Making the program wait would be my last option (how can I do that?

I have no other easy way to add these numbers. I am limited by the program Oracle EDQ options.

Comment: Are you sure it is Java?

Comment: Looks to be JavaScript and not Java. Please learn the difference. I've removed your [tag:java] question tag for you.

Comment: it is javascript, but I can use java like this:var fr = new java.io.FileReader("test5.txt");

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't your Java memory resides in the memory of your server whereas your javascript variables are part of the memory of user's browser i.e. user's system. So you can't have share memory but you definitely can establish link between your server and client through http.

So if you need to save some javascript variables on your server, you can initiate an ajax request from client which will pass the data to server. Once you get it there you can do whatever you like to do with it